# OpenTok and File Sharing

Tags: webrtc, file-sharing, opentok, videochat, tokbox

I am building a video chat website using OpenTok. I have the video and text chat working, (still working on the screen sharing), but I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction regarding file sharing?

I would like both parties to be able to send files to each other, but not really sure how to go about it. Would it be possible to use Peer5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to get the peers to send files to each other.

A first way is to upload the file to your server or to some cloud storage service. Then share the link to the other peers via [OpenTok's Signaling API](https://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/signaling/js/) (which is, presumably, an abstraction over WebRTC's DataChannels). This solution is simple, but not peer-to-peer.

Another solution is to, again, upload the file to a server and share the link to the other peers, but this time have the peers download the file via [Peer5's Downloader](https://peer5.com/downloader/docs). The Peer5 Downloader uses a coordination server to figure out which peers are available to help with the download. If no peers are available, the download will fall back to the HTTP server. This of course only makes sense if the file is being shared with several peers at the same time. In 1-to-1 communications it is pointless.

The previous solution is P2P only in the download part; the user still has to upload the file to a server. Another way, which would be P2P all the way, is to cut the file into chunks, and send them over the OpenTok Signaling API. It is a complicated process but there are several tutorials about this. The tutorials use the WebRTC DataChannel, but it is reasonable to assume that they could be adapted to the Signaling API:

- https://bloggeek.me/send-file-webrtc-data-api/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/#build-a-file-sharing-application

A interesting open source application of a file sharing app using WebRTC is [Sharefest](https://www.sharefest.me/), made by the guys from Peer5. You can use it for inspiration if you are inclined to make such a system.

As a side note, OpenTok seems to be [considering](https://tokbox.com/opentok/starter-kits/) to build a starter kit with sample code about how to integrate OpenTok with Peer5 in a file sharing application. I do not know how such an implementation will work, but I presume it is some variation of my second suggestion here. It could be good to keep an eye on it.

Comment: That's great Elas. I can't seem to find it though. Is it on your profile page because I can't see any email address there.

Comment: Just sent an email :)

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this question, OpenTok's signalling is not based on WebRTC data channels. It is a custom implementation called Rumor and is NOT P2P.